# Math.trunc() not rounding values properly

Tags: javascript, math, truncate

I know there is most definitely a better way to do this in JavaScript but I was kind of just doing something that I know. I am doing another Code Wars challenge and seem to get `12:34:55` when I am supposed to get `12:34:56`.

For the challenge the function is given input in the format of just seconds, ex. `86399`, and then the output should be a human readable format of this.

I don't really know what is wrong here and feel like it has something to do with `Math.trunc()` as my math makes sense.

I would explain the math but it's pretty self explanatory in the code. The only issue seems to be the seconds.

```
function humanReadable(seconds) {
    const hour = Math.trunc((seconds / 60) / 60);
    const mins = Math.trunc((((seconds / 60) / 60) - hour) * 60); 
    const secs = Math.trunc(((seconds / 60) - Math.trunc(seconds / 60)) * 60);

    return `${hour < 10 ? `0${hour}` : hour}:${mins < 10 ? `0${mins}` : mins}:${secs < 10 ? `0${secs}` : secs}`
}
```

Comment: You should just truncate the results of the divisions, not after multiplying.

Comment: There's definitely better ways to do it, you should use modulus to get the remainder after each division.

Comment: There are 86400 seconds in 24 hours - I would expect the result to be 23:59:59. What was the original value that you are given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to floating point not being able to exactly represent numbers

in the case of 45296 - which is 12:34:56

```
A: seconds / 60                    = 754.9333333333333
B: Math.trunc(seconds / 60)        = 754
A - B (should be 0.9333333333333)  =   0.9333333333332803
```

You can see, it's LESS than what it should be, but even 0.9333333333333 * 60 is 55.999999999998 ... truncate that, you get 55

One way to fix it is to

```
const secs = Math.round(((seconds / 60) - Math.trunc(seconds / 60)) * 60);
```

And, maybe also

```
const mins = Math.trunc((((seconds / 60) / 60) - hour) * 60);
```

there are over 600 cases where the minutes "fail"

> Actually, don't do that, it doesn't fix the 600 or so where the minutes are wrong!

Easier way is to use modulo `%` operator

The results of the divisions in this code will always be "integer" only, since the divisor will always be an exact multiple of 60 once you take away the mod 60 (since that's just the remainder after dividing by 60) - Maths! :p

```js
function humanReadable(seconds) {
    const ss = seconds % 60;
    seconds = (seconds - ss) / 60;
    const mm = seconds % 60;
    const hh = (seconds - mm) / 60;
    return [hh,mm,ss].map(v => (''+v).padStart(2, 0)).join(':');
}


console.log(humanReadable(45296))
```

Or, you could just use a date object and let it do all the work for you

```js
function humanReadable(seconds) {
    const d = new Date(0);
    d.setUTCSeconds(seconds);
    const hh = d.getUTCHours().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const mm = d.getUTCMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const ss = d.getUTCSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    return `${hh}:${mm}:${ss}`;
}

console.log(humanReadable(45296))
```

I've also included an alternative way to get the leading zeros - that's just habit for me these says to use padStart etc

before padStart was a thing, instead of

```
hour < 10 ? `0${hour}` : hour
```

I'd do

```
`0${hour}`.substr(-2)
```

But since you're using template literals, you definitely have padStart :p

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use the Modulus to get the remainder after each division of the number as shown below in code snippet.

```js
let d = 86399;
var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
var s = Math.trunc(d % 60);
var result = `${h < 10 ? `0${h}` : h}:${m < 10 ? `0${m}` : m}:${s < 10 ? `0${s}` : s}`
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `d % 3600 % 60` ??? really??? you know that's just `d % 60` right